# Object does not match target type when trying to use SetValue

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
public class ConflictSaver
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<CommonJobDataInfo> _conflictingJobData;
    private readonly DataAccessDataContext _dc;

    public ConflictSaver(IEnumerable<CommonJobDataInfo> conflictingJobData, DataAccessDataContext dc)
    {
        _conflictingJobData = conflictingJobData;
        _dc = dc;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (var data in _conflictingJobData)
        {
            var type = data.ClientBaseObject.GetType();
            var formattedProperty = data.Property.Trim('.').ToUpper();
            foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var currentProperty = data.ClientBaseObject.GetType().GetProperties().First(t => t.Name.Trim() == property.Name.Trim());

                if(currentProperty.Name.ToUpper()== formattedProperty)
                {
                    if (data.UseServerValue)
                        currentProperty.SetValue(currentProperty, data.ServerValue, null);
                    else
                        currentProperty.SetValue(currentProperty, data.ClientValue, null);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I get **Object does not match target type** in the Save() function when I try to call SetValue().   I stink at reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using a wrong overload, and passing a wrong object:

```
if (data.UseServerValue)
    currentProperty.SetValue(data.ClientBaseObject, data.ServerValue);
else
    currentProperty.SetValue(data.ClientBaseObject, data.ClientValue);
```

The property belongs to `data.ClientBaseObject`, so it should be the invocation target. There is no idexer for that property, so [if you are on .NET 4.5 or later](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx), you can skip the third parameter altogether.

Comment: when I compile this, it say "No overload, take 2 parameters".  I'll try it with the null.

Comment: @DJBurb Ah, I did not realize that the 2-arg overload is .NET 4.5 only! The overload with `null` should work.